# Can I serve AMP pages with firebase-storage?

Tags: firebase-storage, amp-html

Since firebase hosting only serve static pages, can I serve [dynamically generated] AMP pages with firebase-storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now with firebase cloud functions, you can use an all-firebase solution:
As an answer to an http request, you can query the database and dynamically generate a amp/html page that is send to the browser.

Here is my approach generating an html page [Firebase HTTP Cloud Functions - Read database once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44317367/4982158)
By now I have developed it further to serve an amp page.

Comment: I figured that out when firebase announce Firebase Hosting with Cloud Functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand AMP correctly, it can be used entirely statically, so there's no reason an AMP page couldn't be hosted on Firebase Hosting.

If you're doing dynamic rendering, you'll want to use App Engine, Compute Engine, or Kubernetes (or similar tech on different cloud platforms).

Comment: I know I can do dynamic rendering with/on other platform/stack, but the idea is to do a complete package with firebase's solution.

Does it mean that I cannot serve AMP pages with firebase-storage? Has anybody tried that before to see if it's workable?

Comment: I deployed test pages with firebase hosting and it worked great.

Comment: Imagine I have a blog with growing numbers of the article which I plan to publish with AMP. Everytime I have a NEW blog post, I will generate a new corresponding AMP page, but there is no way for me to just deploy SINGLE newly added AMP page, without deploying the entile blog site (with potentionlly 1000+ article) on firebase hosting.

Comment: @AndrewSee differential deploys are something we're working on.

You can serve AMP pages from a Google Cloud Storage bucket (which Firebase Storage uses) provided that you set up SSL and DNS and all to point at your bucket (or use Fastly or another CDN to do this for you).

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Thanks for the info, at least I know the firebase team is working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a bucket on Google Cloud Storage as a website. See this article:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

You can also use the firebase storage bucket for that, because firebase storage === google cloud storage.

Regards, Peter