# Cloud Function Firebase, error sending value back

Tags: firebase, httprequest, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send back simple value from firebase but error appearing like this [image]

mycode is :

```
exports.getTotalPrice = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  admin.database().ref('carresult').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var totalPrice = snapshot.val().price;
    res.status(200).send(totalPrice);
  });

});
```

ps. In error 65000 is the value I need it to send back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Express documentation for res.send([body])](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send) indicates:

> The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an
>   Array

In your database, `/carresult/price` is likely stored as a number, making `totalPrice` an invalid parameter to `send()`.  Your options are to store it as a `String` convert it to a `String` before passing to `send()`, or leave it a number and send it back as a property of an object: `send({price: totalPrice})`.

```
exports.getTotalPrice = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  admin.database().ref('carresult').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var totalPrice = snapshot.val().price;
    res.status(200).send(String(totalPrice)); // <= ADDED String()
  });
});
```

Also note that performing a database read (asynchronous) in an HTTPS function is risky, as Frank van Puffelen explains in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43917366/4815718):

> Note that this is a tricky pattern. The call to the database happens
>   asynchronously and may take some time to complete. While waiting for
>   that, the HTTP function may time out and be terminated by the Google
>   Cloud Functions system...As a general rule I'd recommend using a Firebase Database SDK or its REST API to access the database and not rely on a HTTP function as middleware.

Comment: Thank you so much, data sent back to me as string.