# How to get a new database reference inside an onCreate function for sending mail?

Tags: database, firebase

I'm creating a function to send mail whenever a new order is being placed and I want to get a reference to the user email which is inside the database whose path is => Users/uid/email to get the email id of the user to send the mail. How to get this reference inside my function?

I've tried firebase.database.ref(`/Users/${userId}/email`).val(), admin.database.ref(`/Users/${userId}/email`).val(). But none of these work.

```
exports.orderPlaced = functions.database.ref(/Users/{uid}/Bag/Books/{orderId}).onCreate((snapshot, context) => {


const userId = context.params.uid;
const orderid = context.params.orderId;

const refer = firebase.database.ref(/Users/${userId}/email).val();

const mailOptions = {
    from: '"abc" <abc@gmail.com>',
    to: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Order Details',
    html: `<p style="font-size: 16px;">${orderId}</p>
            <br />
        ` // email content in HTML
};

try {
    mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log('mail send');

} 
catch(error) {
    console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error);
}

return null; 
});
```

I want to get the email id of the user but I get the error that firebase is not defined at exports.orderPlaced.functions.database.ref

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting the not defined export.orderPlaced error because firebase uses export  functions to get to the document which in your code is the const refer

To give you an example: `-------exports.sendNotification = functions.database.refer("Users/{user_id}/Email/{email_id}").onWrite(event =>{
    const user_id = event.params.user_id;
    const email_id = event.params.email_id;-----------------`

Comment: I want to get user email, to send him an email, which is at some other place. How do I get that value inside my function?

Comment: To get the a value in the function create a variable/const represented as an object in the database path and you do not need to begin with a dollar sign just use {uid} and then to get the value return the admin.database() please remember to initialise admin by const admin = require('firebase-admin'); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913139/firebase-http-cloud-functions-read-database-once